# Slimscroll scroll down only on div update

Tags: jquery, prototypejs, slimscroll

I am developing a chat with comet and i would like Slimscroll to scroll down only on div update because my chat script update a div by adding new messages to the div.
So far i was able to make Slimscroll scroll down every 2 seconds.

**PROBLEM**
But the problem is that it scrolls down whether the div has changed or not and because of that, the user can not scroll to top. How to make it scroll down only when the div with id `messages_content` has change or increase in size ?

This is my slimscroll code

```
  $(".slimscroll").slimscroll({
        height: "300px",
        color : "#0073b7",
        alwaysVisible: true,
        size: "10px",
        start: 'bottom',
        railVisible: true,
      railColor: '#0073b7',
      railBorderRadius: 0

    }).css("width", "100%");


     // update content every second
  setInterval(function(){

    // update slimscroll every time content changes
   var en_bas = $('.slimscroll').slimscroll({ scrollBy: '400px' });



  }, 2000);
```

And this is my Comet Code that uses prototypejs to fetch informations from the database.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var Comet = Class.create();
Comet.prototype = {

  timestamp: 0,
  url: './messages_private_travail.php?id_du_membre_envoye=<?php echo $id_ojm_peoples; ?>&id_de_l_autre_originale=<?php echo $id_de_l_autre_originale; ?>&id_message=<?php echo addslashes(@$_GET['id_message']); ?>&chat_between=<?php $chat_between = hash('sha512',"Chat Between $id_ojm_peoples AND $id_de_l_autre_originale");  echo $chat_between;  ?>',
  noerror: true,

  initialize: function() { },

  connect: function()
  {
    this.ajax = new Ajax.Request(this.url, {
      method: 'get',
      parameters: { 'timestamp' : this.timestamp },
      onSuccess: function(transport) {
        // handle the server response
        var response = transport.responseText.evalJSON();
        this.comet.timestamp = response['timestamp'];
        this.comet.handleResponse(response);
        this.comet.noerror = true;
      },
      onComplete: function(transport) {
        // send a new ajax request when this request is finished
        if (!this.comet.noerror)
          // if a connection problem occurs, try to reconnect each 5 seconds
          setTimeout(function(){ comet.connect() }, 5000); 
        else
          this.comet.connect();
        this.comet.noerror = false;
      }
    });
    this.ajax.comet = this;
  },

  disconnect: function()
  {
  },


  handleResponse: function(response)

  {
      //$('messages_content').innerHTML += '<div>' + response['msg'] + '</div>';

    $('messages_content').innerHTML += ' ' + response['msg'] + ' ';



    //On appel la fonction qui permet de jouer le son 
    jouer_son('soundmanager2/audio/beep.mp3');  

    //On applique la fonction qui montre que le message a ete lu par le membre
    mettreajour('nombre_nouveaux_messages', 'messages_lire_marquer_comme_lu.php?id_du_membre_envoye=<?php echo $id_ojm_peoples; ?>&id_de_l_autre_originale=<?php echo $id_de_l_autre_originale; ?>&id_message=<?php echo addslashes(@$_GET['id_message']); ?>&chat_between=<?php $chat_between = hash('sha512',"Chat Between $id_ojm_peoples AND $id_de_l_autre_originale");  echo $chat_between;  ?>', '&id_ojm_peoples=<?php echo $id_ojm_peoples; ?>');


  },

  doRequest: function(request)
  {
    new Ajax.Request(this.url, {
      method: 'get',
      parameters: { 'msg' : request, evalScripts: true } 


    });
  }
}
var comet = new Comet();
comet.connect();
</script>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Rather than having to watch for the change event on the DOM, consider calling your scrolling function from the chat script function that adds the content to the div, if possible. For example:

```
handleResponse: function(response) {
  jQuery('#messages_content').append(' ' + response.msg + ' ');
  jQuery('.slimscroll').slimscroll({ scrollBy: '400px' });
}
```

If the objective is to keep it from pushing the user back to the bottom when trying to scroll up, consider also having it only scroll when the user is already at the bottom. That way they can scroll up without being yanked down when a new post comes in, but when they are already at the bottom, it will stay at the bottom:

```
handleResponse: function(response) {
  var messages_content = jQuery('#messages_content');
  var shouldScroll = messages_content[0].clientHeight + messages_content[0].scrollTop === messages_content[0].scrollHeight;
  messages_content.append(' ' + response.msg + ' ');
  if (shouldScroll) {
    jQuery('.slimscroll').slimscroll({ scrollBy: '400px' });
  }
}
```

Comment: I have updated my post for better understanding. I have copied that code you just gave  and placed it under `$('messages_content').innerHTML += ' ' + response['msg'] + ' ';
` but it did not work. Please can you elaborate further ?

Comment: @ManOfGod I might need a little clarification first. In your code, you use:
`$('messages_content').innerHTML += ' ' + response['msg'] + ' ';`
But this shouldn't be a valid jQuery selector (unless the tag is _<messages_content>_). Shouldn't you be using:
`$('#messages_content').append(' ' + response['msg'] + ' ');` instead?

Comment: @ManOfGod I realized after my previous comment that you are using prototypejs for your selectors there instead of jQuery (your question had jQuery in the tags, so I answered based on that). I've updated the code in my answer above, and it should be compatible with yours now.

Comment: No because my code uses prototypejs to take informations from the database. Therefore i have to use jquery in noconflict mode. And when i put `$('#messages_content').append(' ' + response['msg'] + ' ');` instead of  `$('messages_content').innerHTML += ' ' + response['msg'] + ' ';` it does not work. Even when i put it between the noconlict code ```jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {  $('#messages_content').append(' ' + response['msg'] + ' '); });  ```
However if you can convert the prototype code above into Jquery i will be glad to put it in noconflict mode and try again

Comment: I have edited the code but still i am not getting the result. Please visit 
[UseChurch](http://usefaith.voiedusucces.net/) and log in using username cadnel and password cadnel. And then click on the message envelope or after login go to [UseChurch Chat](http://usefaith.voiedusucces.net/messages_lire.php?id_du_membre_envoye=7&id_message=219&id_de_l_autre=1&chat_between=2b1d6c8a4bdb2a2bc22d6892692e450cd5899193642b82187a4b3e9fae819c9a3e812a0e8df5faef4ec229903c3089030851f4cf98ad7a378482bb60610dd6bd) to check a demo after i have added the code you gave me

Comment: @ManOfGod I've converted the code back to jQuery noconflict. Try using the first example first. If that isn't working, add this to it (below the append line): `jQuery('#messages_content')[0].scrollTop = jQuery('#messages_content')[0].scrollHeight - jQuery('#messages_content')[0].clientHeight;` That should force the scroll to jump to the bottom, just in case the slimscroll is the problem there.